# usage of time and place in the cleft sentence

Tags: cleft-constructions

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/it

In this link, I found the sentence '' It is August that you are going on holiday''.

I wonder why it is not ''in August''?
I think the sentence '' It is in August that you are going on holiday'' will be sound.

The second question is ''Can I use where/when in it-cleft sentence?''

> E.g, 
>   It was the market where I met her.

Comment: Whether the statement with **where** would be considered a "cleft" depends on the definition of "cleft".  Although I consider the *where*-clause similar to a *that*-clause in this construction, there are linguists who would disagree with me, who would call the phrase introduced by *where* a locative complement and say that such a sentence was not a cleft. I don't keep up with contemporary grammar, and would defer to them in such matters.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in meaning is one of time granularity.

*It is August that X* - Speaker is thinking in terms of months, e.g. vacations, etc. are allocated by month, not by anything smaller.

*It is in August that X* - Speaker is thinking in terms of weeks or days, but is concerned with what is happening in August.

> The second question is ''Can I use where/when in it-cleft sentence?''

*Where* as relative pronoun (or any relative pronoun really) doesn't care if the subject of the first clause is *it*.

> It was yesterday that I saw  him.
>
> It was the moldy one which made him sick.
>
> It was 4:00 when he disappeared.

Comment: I don't buy this distinction. Strictly speaking, ***August*** with no preposition is "invalid" anyway. Consider, for example, *It's 1955 that Einstein died*, which is syntactically equivalent - where almost all native speakers would insist on the preposition ***in*** being included. OP's prepositionless version is just "marginally acceptable" sloppy speech, not a valid way of conveying a fine nuance.